# how to show a calculated value in textbox in an windows form application in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to calculate the area of circle. i take the value in one textbox named as textBox1 and I have to show the calculated answer into another textbox named as textBox2. I did the first part but don't know how to do the second one. Plz guide...

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AreaOfCircle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int radius;
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    double area; 

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radius = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        area = PI * radius * radius;

        textBox2.Text = area;    /// here it is showing error now        
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What isn't working, what have you tried. show us some code of what you tried. it helps us find the issue, rather then I want this to happen please write the code.

Comment: Please get into the habit of naming your controls properly.  For example, since your `textBox1` will hold the radius, name it `txtRadius`.  That makes your code clearer for those who try to help and for yourself when you come back to the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:Input on textbox1 = radius.

```
double radius, area;

if(double.TryParse(txtRadius.Text,out radius)
{
      area = 3.14*radius*radius;
}

txtResult.Text = area;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double outValue;
            if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out outValue))
            {
                var answer = Math.PI * Math.Pow(outValue, 2);
                textBox2.Text = answer.ToString("#.##");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **area.ToString()** might solve your problem but you should use **Convert.ToString(area)** instead.

If you are getting value *null* in  any case then Convert.ToString() will not throw runtime exception but ToString will.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have a mistake in what you are doing, however it does seem that you have forgotten one small step. When you hover over `area` in the line `textBox2.Text = area;` it says

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'

that in it self points out that if you want to put something into a textbox you need to have it as a string. There are multiple ways to convert area into a string. some examples are:

```
//Convert and then place it in the textbox    
string temp = Convert.ToString(area)
textBox2.Text = temp;  
//convert directly (2 diffrent ways)
textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(area);  
textBox2.Text = area.ToString(); 
//or use String Format this accepts int's, double's, floats, strings and other variables
//and allowes you to format them how you like, for this one i chose to go for
//2 digits after the decimal seperator
textBox2.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}",area);
```

I hope this is to use to you and that you learned something from it for in the future. if there are any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: ThanQ... Its solved. I used "textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(area);"

Comment: Please accept the awnser that you found most usefull. By doing that you let others know that the question is awnsered, and it has some effects on the automated post deleting program.

Answer (score -1):

**You must convert the `area` to `String`**

```
textBox2.Text = area.ToString();
```

Comment: I really don't know why people downvote my answer !!!!!  but @PrabhatRanjan if my answer solves your problem please consider accepting my answer and let's forget about downvoters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sir PLEASE can you explain to me why people downvotes my answer? I am really disappointed  :/